# How to handle .hpp not included in any .cpp in a static library

Tags: c++, makefile, static-libraries

I am writing a makefile for building a library, this is an excerpt of it, relevant to the question I am asking:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
OUT = my_library     #there is a .cpp file called my_library

$(OUT): $(OBJS)
    ar rvs $(OUT).a $(OUT).o

$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(SCRS) $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

This has the problem that if I have a dangling header file, with dangling I mean that it is not included in any .cpp file, the makefile does not consider it for the compilation.

What should I do? To list them manually and to add them as a dependency and target of `$(OBJS)`? I do not think this is the way I have to follow.

Comment: If the header file is not included in any .cpp file why should it be compiled? It's obviously not used

Comment: because it is a static library, so it can still be included in the project that is using the library

Comment: I don't understand - did you implement the library in the header file? And who is supposed to use that header file? Usually a header-only library does not need to be compiled to a static library

Comment: For instance I use the header files to include submodules of the library all in one shot. I think you are right, I can just skip them and those headers will be compiled by the final code using the library

Comment: A static library can have an associated header (or multiple). I don't see the problem.

Comment: Why not simply include it in any .cpp file?

Comment: If you need the header alone to be compiled, then you have code in the header that doesn't belong in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Header files simply define what's in the source files or generate code *when they are used*. In the case of a library file, the code they generate will be produced in the calling code, not the library code, so nothing needs to be generated when the library is compiled.